# Routing Layer does not show on Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, pgrouting

I am trying to develop a routing application. I have published my layers and SQL view on GeoServer. Currently I am trying to display my pgRouting Layer on my leaflet map using markers as start and end points. The route does not display. The markers get the start and and end point coordinates but do not display the route. I have created the following code:

```
var selectedPoint = null;

var sourceMarker = L.marker([33.5183, 73.1789], {
    draggable: true
})
.on("dragend", function(e) {
    selectedPoint = e.target.getLatLng(); console.log(selectedPoint)
    getRoute(); 
})
.addTo(map); 

// draggbale marker for destination point.Note the marker is initialized with an initial destination positon
var targetMarker = L.marker([33.5191, 73.1768], {
    draggable: true
})
.on("dragend", function(e) {
    selectedPoint = e.target.getLatLng(); console.log(selectedPoint)
    getRoute(); 
})
.addTo(map); 

function getRoute(){
    var start = sourceMarker.getLatLng();  console.log(start)
    var end = targetMarker.getLatLng();   
    var viewparams = [
        'y1:' + start.lng, 'x1:' + start.lat,
        'y2:' + end.lng, 'x2:' + end.lat
      ];
      var routing = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8010/geoserver/wms' , {
        layers: 'IST_Mosaic:pgRouting',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    });
    routing.addTo(map); console.log(routing)
}
getRoute();
```

The Request Parameters for OpenLayers and Leaflet (viewed using Browser Debugger) are different.

For OpenLayers:

```
'http://localhost:8010/geoserver/IST_Mosaic/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=IST_Mosaic%3ApgRouting&viewparams=x1%3A73.17880344047548%3By1%3A33.51828211053321%3Bx2%3A73.1764323677063%3By2%3A33.51912291147366&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=2025&HEIGHT=900&BBOX=8144985.631309435%2C3963897.360405983%2C8147404.146657521%2C3964972.2561162435'
```

For Leaflet:

```
'http://localhost:8010/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=IST_Mosaic%3ApgRouting&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=8145741.230294664,3964024.2868692423,8146046.978407806,3964330.0349823823'
```

The Code working successfully in OpenLayers Looks like this:

```
var params = {
    LAYERS: 'IST_Mosaic:pgRouting',
    FORMAT: 'image/png',
    REQUEST: 'GetMap'
  }

  // The "start" and "destination" features.
  var startPoint = new ol.Feature();
  var destPoint = new ol.Feature();

  // The vector layer used to display the "start" and "destination" features.
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [startPoint, destPoint]
    })
  });
  map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

  // A transform function to convert coordinates from EPSG:3857
  // to EPSG:4326.
  var transform = ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

  // Register a map click listener.
  map.on('click', function(event) {
    if (startPoint.getGeometry() == null) {
      // First click.
      startPoint.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(event.coordinate));
    } else if (destPoint.getGeometry() == null) {
      // Second click.
      destPoint.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(event.coordinate));
      // Transform the coordinates from the map projection (EPSG:3857)
      // to the server projection (EPSG:4326).
      var startCoord = transform(startPoint.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
      var destCoord = transform(destPoint.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
      console.log(startCoord,destCoord);
      var viewparams = [
        'x1:' + startCoord[0], 'y1:' + startCoord[1],
        'x2:' + destCoord[0], 'y2:' + destCoord[1]
      ];
      console.log(viewparams);
      params.viewparams = viewparams.join(';');
      result = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8010/geoserver/IST_Mosaic/wms',
          params: params
        })
      });
      console.log(result)
      map.addLayer(result);
    }
  });
```

In Leaflet, the function gets the coordinates after the marker is dragged and stopped but the route layer does not show. I have tried the same in OpenLayers and it works fine. I can't seem to figure out the issue. Can anyone suggest a solution or a useful hint? I am really stuck.

Comment: What do you see in browser debugger, network section? What do the requests look like? Did you compare them with requests in OpenLayers implementation where things work? You are setting `viewparams` object, but it's not used anywhere.

Comment: Using console.log to check, the source marker and target marker get the coordinates when I stop dragging them. And I also get all the parameters for pgRouting layer as well. The crs, wms params etc all display properly in the browser debugger. But the layer does not display. In OpenLayers the layer shows similar params. I can't see any difference in the params for both.

Comment: What do you see in result of WMS requests in browser network debugger?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010294/routing-layer-does-not-show-on-leaflet-map

Comment: @TomazicM The WMS requests show GetMap request.

Comment: Of course it's GetMap request. I'm talking about parameters. Single request should look something like this: https://prostor4.gov.si/ows2-m-pub/wms?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=SI.GURS.ZPDZ%3ADOF050_D48&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&queryable=false&transitionefect=resize&width=512&height=512&crs=EPSG%3A3912&bbox=400768.0037525206,62920.000334048644,417152.00372809573,79304.00035906397. Is it the same in Leaflet and OpenLayers?

Comment: Oh Okay, Well they're different in both. In Leaflet: [link](http://localhost:8010/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=IST_Mosaic%3ApgRouting&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=8146658.474634087,3964330.0349823823,8146964.222747227,3964635.7830955214)

Comment: And In OpenLayers: [link](http://localhost:8010/geoserver/IST_Mosaic/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=IST_Mosaic%3ApgRouting&viewparams=x1%3A73.1788302625656%3By1%3A33.51829105526707%3Bx2%3A73.17639481678007%3By2%3A33.519131856120595&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=1196&HEIGHT=900&BBOX=8145284.810615456%2C3963898.5547345495%2C8146713.227581535%2C3964973.45044481)

Comment: Edit your question and include both requests in the body of the question. And delete cross-posted question on StackOverflow, otherwise this one is most likely to be closed.

Comment: Done. I have deleted the stack overflow question and updated this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at OpenLayers WMS request that is working, then Leaflet WMS request should be constructed using the same parameters:

```
var viewparams = 'y1:' + start.lat + ';' + 'x1:' + start.lng + ';' + 'y2:' + end.lat + ';' + 'x2:' + end.lng

var routing = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8010/geoserver/IST_Mosaic/wms', {
  layers: 'IST_Mosaic:pgRouting',
  format: 'image/png',
  transparent: true,
  version: '1.3.0',
  viewparams: viewparams
});
```

Comment: [This](http://localhost:8010/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=IST_Mosaic%3ApgRouting&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&viewparams=y1%3A33.51829350903833%3Bx1%3A73.178848028183%3By2%3A33.519044863359696%3Bx2%3A73.17679882049562&height=256&width=256&crs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=8146046.978407806,3964024.2868692423,8146352.726520946,3964330.0349823823) shows when I move my markers, but it's still not visible on the map.

Comment: The network actually shows me many pgRouting layers with different coordinates, but the link I mentioned in the above comment is the only time it displays when viewed using wms.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, though. I feel like I am close to a solution.

Comment: I have added the OpenLayers code that is working for me in the Question. Maybe that will help to find a solution

Comment: Ups, only now I realized I included OpenLayers code instead of Leaflet code in my answer. I'll correct this later today.

Comment: Could you please update the answer for the Leaflet code. Thank you.

Comment: Answer updated with Leaflet code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works perfectly, but there is another issue. I have several other layers loaded onto my map from geoserver. And the routing layer displays only when I have switched all other layers off. Is there a way to have all the other layers and routing layer display simultaneously?

Comment: See concept of map panes in Leaflet https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-pane and an example how to use them https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: Thank You so much for all the help :)